# Is there any way to make an apk run on emulator?

Tags: android-studio, apk

I have an apk that does not install on emulators or tablets, I was wondering if it has any method?

Already opened the file with android studio, apk clone [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQs8k.png)

I get this message:

> The app does not support this device, install and use on your mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try getting an app such as BlueStacks, it should be able to run APKs.

Comment: I tried, but this apk only works on mobile, I was wondering if there is any way to remove this lock

Comment: No, I don't believe there is, sorry to say.